# send String from java to js, using current project

Tags: javascript, spring

Before ask this question, I have already read the forum and tried a lot of from forum suggestions. I do not know , maybe i do not clearly understand or maybe the reason that i apply to my current project, however answer on the forum is not working in my project

- Java:

  ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/warehouseWhisky", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
   public ModelAndView viewAllWhiskyInWarehouse() {

  Iterable<WhiskyDTO> list = whiskyService.seeAllWhisky();
  String  email = receiveEmailFromSecurity.getEmail();
  System.out.println(email);
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
  modelAndView.addObject("viewAvailableWhisky", list);
  modelAndView.addObject("email", email);

  modelAndView.setViewName("whisky");
  return modelAndView;
  }
  ```

  This code correct, I recive in HTML string:

  ```
   <input type="button" id="someThingNew" th:value="${email}"/>
  ```

  [image]
  But I didn't recieve this parameters in js:

  ```
    var nameUser = $("#someThingNew").val();
       console.log(nameUser);
  ```

Comment: What are you calling? It can find the mappings - but the issue in the 2nd variant is you are missing email from the URL. Focus on the first method - what is the URL. Provide some log for this url

Comment: I send email from java, from DB

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused because of the special characters in email like '@'. In other word you cannot send email address using `@PathVariable` (with ordinary routing configuration). Instead of `@PathVariable`, you can send email using `@RequestParam` and send it as a query parameter.

Comment: can you show example, I know how send from js to java, from HTML to java use '@RequestParam', but I don't understand how send from java to JS use '@RequestParam'

Comment: Why do you want to send from Java to JS. Keep one thing in mind that your client side JS script can not handle the requests, so you can not send as a request param but you can send in response If you want.

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of "send from Java to JS", anyway you can send email address to your controller as a query parameter using `@RequestParam`. After that you have the email address in the scope of method and you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first method is probably fine - just you are calling the wrong URL. What is your server mapping? I would expect something like -

> http://localhost:8080/warname/warehouseWhisky/test@test.com

The issue with the second one is that its expecting similar to the following - which is why you are getting a 500

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/warehouseWhisky/{email}")
```

Comment: No - your server will say something like localhost:8080/<myapp>/

Comment: try localhost:8080/warehouseWhisky/warehouseWhisky/test@test.com

Comment: I do shoppingCart and when User click on button "Buy", I want to send his email to JS from java, and send him, on the his email, the order from shoppingCart. I don't know what email will be

Comment: No its a test of the url - it should not return 404. In fact replace the method body with a sys out. Incidentally why do you take email as a param then overwrite?